# How to create click to chat link to WhatsApp which works both desktop and Android browser?

Tags: android, html, hyperlink, deep-linking, whatsapp

I'm making Jekyll page. I wanted to have a link - when clicked it should start WhatsApp. It should work both on desktop browser and Android browser.

When I follow [official docs](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/26000030/?category=5245251), then click on recommended there link `https://wa.me/15551234567?text=MESSAGE!!` in desktop browser redirects me to some weird url

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567&text=MESSAGE%21%21&source=&data=&app_absent=
```

And content looks pretty ugly on Firefox (on Chrome it looks fine):

[image]

There is link (blue "Send" text with `<a href=...`) which when clicked - goes to `https://web.whatsapp.com/` but this should rather go to `https://web.whatsapp.com/` right away without clicking.

On the other hand, when I make the link to reference this url `https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=123123123&text=MESSAGE!!` - it works on desktop browser (i.e. it goes directly to `https://web.whatsapp.com/`) but on Android browser it opens page `whatsapp.com` while it should start WhatsApp's native application or start `https://web.whatsapp.com/`.

Am I doing it wrong or it's WhatsApp weirdness?

Comment: The wa.me link which you said to "looks pretty ugly" looks fine on my side. Check your network inspector, it might failed to load the CSS for whatever reason. As for the other links, they're not a documented feature, meaning Whatsapp is free to change (and broke your app) anytime they want. As for Android deeplinking, in my phone it doesn't work on Firefox, only on Chrome,

Comment: that's funny! I've checked your comment and on desktop: firefox looks ugly; chrome looks fine.